# libgdx wrong coordinates when moving group

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Consider the following snippet:

```
class Level implements Screen{

    Stage stage;
    Group spaceInvaderGroup;

    public Level(){
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(120, 200));
        spaceInvaderGroup = new Group();

        spaceInvaderGroup.addActor(new SpaceInvader);
        spaceInvaderGroup.addActor(new SpaceInvader);
        spaceInvaderGroup.addActor(new SpaceInvader);
        spaceInvaderGroup.addActor(new SpaceInvader);
    }

    public void render(){
        spaceInvaderGroup.moveBy(0.1F,0);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

}

class SpaceInvader extends Actor{

    private Sprite sprite;
    private Vector2 stageCoords;

    SpaceInvader(){
        sprite = new Sprite;
        //set Textures of sprite here
        //bounds are set here using SI units        
    }

    @override
    public void draw(Spritebatch batch, float parentAlpha){
        batch.draw(sprite);
        super.draw();
    }

    @override
    public void act(){
        setGlobalPosition();
        sprite.setPosition(stageCoords.x, stageCoords.y);   
        super.act();
    }

    private void setGlobalPosition() {   
        stageCoords = localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(0, 0));
    }

}
```

I want to make a SpaceInvaders game in libgdx. Since the space invaders move in a coordinated manner, I decided to put them in a `group` and move the group using a `moveBy` method. To draw the spaceInvaders, i get their `stage coordinates` and draw the Sprite using the stage coordinates. The problem is, that the stage coordinates are not correct. My question is, what is the correct way to draw actors from different groups at the same time? Is my approach correct, to first convert all local corrdinates to stage coordinates, and if so, why is my result wrong?

Comment: why you're using Actor having Sprite. Use Image instead of that, Image is an actor having drawing property ?

Comment: you're not using localX and localY  in setGlobalPosition() method. You're t Change position of Sprite not Inheriated actor. Each time it return same getX() and getY() in setGlobalPosition().